# A Property of Lyapunov Index

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

Lyapunov Index of a function is defined as
$\lambda(f)=\lim\sup_{t\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{t} \log||{f(t)}||$,
where $f:R\rightarrow R^d$

A property of Lyapunov Index is $\lambda(f+g)\le\max(\lambda(f),\lambda(g))$.
It is said in every book that it is easy to prove, but I don't know how to prove it.

Also, another property is $\lambda(||f||^\alpha)=\alpha\lambda(f),$ for $\alpha\in R$
But if $\alpha<0$, for example $\alpha=-1$,  $\lambda(||f||^{-1})=\lim\sup_{t\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{t} \log||{f(t)}||^{-1}=-\lim\inf_{t\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{t}\log||f(t)||$
it is not certainly equal to $-\lambda(f)$. Am I wrong?

> Arnold: Random Dynamical Systems. Chap3

Comment: I don't see how this can be true. If $f=g$, then
$$
\lambda(2f) = \limsup_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t} \log\| 2 f(t) \| = \limsup_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}  (\log 2 + \log \| f(t) \| ) > \limsup_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t}  \log \| f(t) \| = \lambda(f) = \max(\lambda(f),\lambda(g)).
$$
Do you have a reference?

Comment: Actually $\lambda(2f)=\lambda(f)$

Comment: Ok, I got that from your statement. Do you see what I did wrong?

Comment: @Vincent $\log 2/t \to 0$, so $\lambda(2f) = \lambda(f)$.

Comment: Ahh true, I should be more aware of the $\liminf$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$
$$ \norm{f+g} \le 2\max\{\norm f, \norm g\}$$
as the logarithm is monotone
$$ \log \norm{f+g}  \le \log 2 + \max\{\log \norm f, \log\norm g\} $$
Dividing by $t$ and taking the limes superior gives 
$$ \lambda(f+g) \le \max\{\lambda(f), \lambda(g)\} $$
as $\frac{\log 2}t \to 0$.

Comment: Nice, thanks so much